# Selenium chrome driver to open website c# with headless

Tags: c#, selenium

This is my code with open web.whatsapp.com url and I add argument "Headless" so not open page but give the selection of the which browser to open.
So how to avoid browser selection and get page.
but without "Headless" then easy to open webpage and not asking any option to selection

```
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
Driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
```

[image: img]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `give selection of browser`? Are you seeing any error? Update the question with error stack trace.

Comment: Actually not selection of browser option direct open page

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding a double-dash before the argument.

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
```

Comment: what version worked for you? using the latest packages but won't budge.